# Vim - execute command when changed buffer is beein written

Tags: vim, command, buffer, execute

Hello fellow Vim users.

I am trying to execute a command when I write a buffer with `:w`.
But the command should only be executed if I changed the content of the buffer.

I thought somthing like this maybe:

```
autocmd BufWritePost * if modified | echo 'execute command' | endif
```

How to I do that?

**Edit:**

I found the solution

```
autocmd BufWritePre * if &modified | echo 'execute command' | endif
```

Apperently I can not write modified without '&' in front it.

Comment: By the way `echo 'execute command'` will print something but the next echo, something like `bla bla bla written` will come shortly after. The message wont be seen because of that. The commands will still be executed.

Answer (score 2):

As you've already found out, you can check the buffer-local `'modified'` flag for that. For the syntax, a `&` needs to be prepended to the option name.

Alternatively, if you use the `:update` command instead of `:write`, the buffer will only be persisted (and the autocmd triggered) where there are actual changes; for unchanged buffers, this command is a no-op.

Many users have a mapping similar to this:

```
nnoremap <C-S>      :<C-U>update<CR>
vnoremap <C-S>      :<C-U>update<CR>gv
inoremap <C-S>      <C-O>:update<CR>
```